# What is the significance of this 'load' method in extjs?

Tags: javascript, extjs, sencha-touch

For the listeners part of this data store in sencha touch, what exactly does the 'load' event mean? I searched the api documentation but was unable to find an explanation in the data store section nor the observable class section.

```
     new Ext.data.Store({
        model: "",
        proxy: {
            type: "ajax",
            url : "/search/json/",
            reader: {
                type: "json",
                root: "searchResult"
            }
        },
        listeners: {
            load: myapp.results    //Note: myapp.results is a function defined elsewhere
        }
    });
```

As an additional note, if anyone knows of a reference which lists all of the listener 'eventnames' such as load, and their significance I would be grateful if they would be so kind as to post them here. (The sencha documentation only says: 'The name of the event to listen for. May also be an object who's property names are event names. See' and ends at See )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This event is fired when the data is loaded.
You must assign a function to use it.

```
listeners:{
     load:function(store,records,options){
          // Do stuff, you can access here to the loaded store, the loaded records and options
     }
 }
```

It will be called each time the data is loaded, on refresh, on page change, etc.

Answer (score 2):

[Sencha API](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/touch/docs/?class=Ext.data.Store#load?class=Ext.data.Store) says "Fires whenever the store reads data from a remote data source." There is all different event-names too. Am I missing something?

Comment: I don't think that 'load' is the same 'load' I am referring to.

Comment: For example, if you look at config options of that api page and look up listeners you will see events such as 'click', 'dblclick' etc which are not listed alongside the 'load' definition.Further, I am not understanding how 'fires whenever the stores reads data from a remote source' would relate to the code above.

Comment: click, dblclick and so on are element-listeners. Basic dom-stuff. They are not fired by Sencha, only rerouted to those listener methods when dom-event applies. The events listed in api are Sencha's own.

Comment: @David Watkins: It's exactly the same `load`.

Answer (score 0):

Consider two components that is one is dependent upon another component which is to used as input by it in such a case we can make use of load function.